# a .net replacement for DHtmlEdit

Tags: .net, richtextbox

We are now in the process of converting an old VB6 project into C#. We're looking for a replacement to DHtmlEdit: We currently use this old component in several forms, to edit rich text and export it to HTML. We need something with full Rich Text editing capabilities, that can also read HTML, raise events when links are clicked, etc.

Can anyone recommend a good .Net component for this?

EDIT: in case this wasn't clear, we're looking for something for a WinForms application.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the WebBrowser control I believe.  At least if you aren't looking to go with a third party control.

I haven't tried it with rich text, but that would be a place to start.

You might look at the Chromium web browser control also.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for something that allows you to edit HTML using a wysiwyg UI. WebBrowser is for browsing only, isn't it?

Comment: You can use the WebBrowser control to host the editor. You have access to the DOM and can extract the HTML.